# Writing to a PHP Session Variable from Ajax

Tags: php, session-variables

Ok, this is starting to annoy me, as it's quite simply and works elsewhere, but on this current task it doesn't, so here I go!

There is a main page which relies on either a session variable being set or not to display certain information.
Let's say this page is located here: http://dev.example.com/some_page.php
e.g.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["some_var"])) { /* it's set so do whatever */ }
else { /* not set so do whatever else.. */ }
```

There is an ajax page triggered by jQuery $.ajax() to call and set this session variable to null to change the action of the main page, let's say it's located here: http://dev.example.com/ajax/some_ajax_page.php

It's code looks like so:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    $_SESSION["some_var"] = null;
```

When the main page is reloaded after the ajax is triggered, the session var "some_var" is still intact, but if it's echoed after the "null" in the ajax page then it is set to "null".

Basically it doesn't seem to write to the global session, only to the local path.

Does this make sense?

Any help please? Also if you want more clarification with anything let me know!

Comment: $_SESSION is a superglobal and is always "set".

Comment: use `$_SESSION["some_var"] != ''` rather than `isset`

Comment: are you calling session_start() in your main page also?

Comment: There is another way to make it, I think. set cookie in javascript, and use $_COOKIE instead of $_SESSION.

Comment: @Marc B Not on my server (php 5.2.9) or codepad: http://codepad.org/id1cWMfk

Comment: I did a var_dump($_SESSION["some_var"]) and it shows the one on the main page as the value and the one on the ajax page with a value. However, the session_id() is the same on both!

Comment: @MassimilianoArione, I am using session_start() on both pages but still no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the application I was working on had it's own session_handler and if it was not included before requesting the session data, it was always invalid, eventhough it was the same session_id.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what was done with session_handler?  How did you fix your issue?  Was something else executing `session_start()`?

Comment: @Scott, there should only ever be 1 `session_start()`. I was using a MySQL database to store the values instead of the conventional file storage.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the check for session.  If this is the only file your calling just do this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["some_var"] = null;
```

Also, are you using framework that auto-regenerates session ID on each request?  If so, you'll might have problems.

If you have a dev machine to play with and permissions to do so, you can manually delete all sessions in the /var/lib/php/session/ directory.  As you use your site, only one session file should be created.  You can also inspect that file to see what is getting written and when.

Comment: If I don't do the check for session it moans about it in the server logs... that's the only reason it's added..

Comment: @hsmoore.com If you check several pages, are the session id's the same?

Comment: I have checked this by doing echo session_id(); and I get the same value for both pages, eventhough the data does not match.

Comment: @hsmoore.com  If you use the Ajax call to return the session ID to the  browser, and you print it out is it also the same value?

Comment: the value is the same for echo session_id() whether it's in the main page or the ajax page.

Comment: If you break the request into 3 distinct page views instead on one view with ajax that refreshes, does it work fine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12765/discussion-between-hsmoore-com-and-ray)

Answer (score 1):

The `session_start()` function will handle the attempt to create and persist a session for you, as defined by PHP's configuration, or optionally at runtime if you set your own save handler. Make sure you read the documentation here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

For your code, you want to make sure to call `session_start()` at the beginning of any page in which you'd like to save or access session variables. So your page above may look like:

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'some value';
```

Then in a different page you can try to access that value:

```
 <?php

 session_start();

 if ($_SESSION['myvar'] == 'some value') {

   // do something

 }
```

That should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using different sessions vars. One for the AJAX call and another for the normal pages calls. This may occur when you do not init both call in the same way (or using the same starting code that initializes the sessions)
Be sure to session_start() both calls using the same [session_id](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-id.php).

```
// try in both calls
session_start();
echo session_id(); // must return the same id in both calls
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use unset? It is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I don't like using unset() on session variables as it is actually unpredictable and doesn't always work, so I have decided to set unused ones to null instead these days.